# React Native project version upgrade error: v0.56 to v0.60, iOS fails

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, upgrade, react-native-ios

I'm currently upgrading one of my projects built in `React Native v0.56` to latest `v0.60`. Created a new project with version `v0.60` and updated all the packages used in previous version of app, but now facing weird errors.

I've already tried all the possible solutions mentioned in Git and Stack overflow. None of them worked for me. I've also tried to remove plugins one by one and then adding them but not able to find cause of the error.

**iOS:**

In `iOS`, all the packages by default autolinks as per `v0.60`, but I got error of linking in very first package, I've tried manual linking too, not working.

[image: Package Linking Error - @react-native-community/netinfo]

Answer (score 0):

After manual linking do `cd ios` and then `pod install`. This will not be done by autolinking and you have to do it yourself. On iOS on my project i had to manual link on iOS almost every library and almost all of them needed a `pod install`

Answer (score 0):

use upgrade helper from react native community [Upgrade Helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.56.0&to=0.60.0)